# How to add Response_type id_token+code in login url in angular using msadal library

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, ms-adal-angular

We are using msadal librabry for Azure ad B2C login, now I want to add response_type in https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
url while user login.

below is code used for login

```
 if (!this.msAdal.isAuthenticated && !environment.isTestEnvironment) {
                this.msAdal.login();
            }
```

used MsAdalAngular6Service library for msadal

I have check adal.js library file, in this for login method response type id_token is set as hardcoded, so I think we can not assign response type in msadal, so what will be the solution if I want to pass response type as code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `oidc-client-js` library for Azure AD B2C, refer to this [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-profile-editing-user-flow-in-angular-using-oidc-client-js-81265f8e8fbf). You can find the accompanying sample project [here](https://github.com/taithienbo/oidc-client-js-azure-integration-ex).

In **oidc-settings.json**:

```
{
  "client_id": "47ea6724-b21f-46de-9d17-7425920f77e4",
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
  "signupSigninPolicy": "b2c_1_signupandsignin",
  "tenantName": "taithienbo",
  "response_type": "id_token token",  // set response_type here
  "loadUserInfo": false,
  "response_mode": "fragment",
  "scope": "https://taithienbo.onmicrosoft.com/mywebapi/user_impersonation openid profile",
  "editProfilePolicy": "B2C_1_a_profile_edit"
}
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: What are code changes required in C# startup project?

Comment: Please try the sample: https://github.com/damienbod/dotnet-template-angular/tree/master/dotnet-angular-azure-ad-oidc

Comment: Thank you for your reply, currently we have stopped this task, if we do this in future then I will try with this and accept your answer

Comment: Hi @Pamela Peng , I have tried this sample of oidc, but it will not allow me to set response_ type as code id_token, it will throw error  'configure incorrect, invalid response_type:code id_token'

Comment: How to get code state and session state in OIDC, because code is added in URL only, it is not stored anywhere